# Converting an array to 0s and 1s

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an array `A = [13, 15, 17]`. I want to create a new array `B` such that all entries apart from its 13th, 15th and 17th entries are `0`, and each of these three are `1`'s. How can I do this?

Comment: Suppose A = [5]. I want B as [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
B = [int(i+1 in A) for i in range(max(A))]
```

For each number in the range from `0` to the highest number in `A`, we take `int(i+1 in A)`.  `i+1 in A` will be a boolean value.  If that number is in `A`, the result will be `True`.  Otherwise it will be `False`.  Since `bool` inherits from `int`, we can easily convert it to a normal integer with `int()`.